# Object create on JS 1.2 with parameter list

Tags: javascript

I didn't find way how to create an object in prehistorical javascript (probably 1.2):

- I have array with parameters.
- I have a constructor function.

Now I want to do something like:

```js
var constructor = ...;
return constructor.apply(.?., parameterList);
```

or

```js
var constructor = ...;
return new constructor(...parameterList);
```

Is it possible to do in javascript? I've found one hack which is creating duplicate objects.

```js
var constructor = ...;
var instance = new constructor;
parameterList.length > 0 ? constructor.apply(instance, parameterList) : null;
return instance;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> **Edit 1.0**
>
> So I've found quite interesting solution:
>
> ```js
> var instance = (function (constructor, parameterList) {
>     var creator = constructor;
>
>     function Constructor() {
>         creator.apply(this, parameterList);
>     }
>
>     Constructor.prototype = creator.prototype;
>     return new Constructor;
> }(...constructor function comes here..., parameterList));
> ```
>
> Some disadvantage could be showing `Constructor` all the times (even that true type is probably created).
>
> **Edit 1.0.1**
>
> Credits goes here: http://tobyho.com/2010/11/22/javascript-constructors-and/